# cannot set user roles when integrate SpagoBI and LDAP

Tags: ldap

I face the problem of roles setting when integrate with LDAP and SpagoBI 4.1.0, I can logon but cannot setting user roles by LDAP.

My LDAP xml setting as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!--  SERVER -->
<HOST>********</HOST>
<PORT>389</PORT>    
<ADMIN_USER>********</ADMIN_USER>
<ADMIN_PSW>******</ADMIN_PSW> <!-- password in clear text -->
<BASE_DN>DC=***,DC=com</BASE_DN> <!-- base domain, if any -->

<!-- USERS -->
<USER_SEARCH_PATH>ou=People</USER_SEARCH_PATH> <!-- SpagoBI will look for users under this node -->
<USER_OBJECT_CLASS>applUser</USER_OBJECT_CLASS> <!-- class for users' objects -->
<USER_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME>uid</USER_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME> <!-- name of the attribute containing the user identifier -->
 <!-- name of the attribute(*) containing the user name -->
<USER_NAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME>cn</USER_NAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
<!-- (*) SPAGOBI attribute, not LDAP attribute!!! It must match the "name" attribute of one USER_ATTRIBUTE tag below -->
<USER_MEMBEROF_ATTRIBUTE_NAME>memberOf</USER_MEMBEROF_ATTRIBUTE_NAME> <!-- this attribute has to contain the list of groups the user belongs to -->

<!-- list of the users' attributes to be loaded when querying the LDAP -->
<USER_ATTRIBUTE name="uid">uid</USER_ATTRIBUTE> <!-- LDAP attribute to be considered as SpagoBI attribute -->
<USER_ATTRIBUTE name="cn">cn</USER_ATTRIBUTE> 
<USER_ATTRIBUTE name="memberOf">memberOf</USER_ATTRIBUTE>

<!-- GROUPS -->
<GROUP_SEARCH_PATH>ou=Groups</GROUP_SEARCH_PATH> <!-- SpagoBI will look for groups under this node -->
<GROUP_OBJECT_CLASS>groupOfNames</GROUP_OBJECT_CLASS> <!-- class for groups' objects -->
<GROUP_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME>cn</GROUP_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME> <!-- the attribute containing the name of the group -->
<GROUP_MEMBERS_ATTRIBUTE_NAME>member</GROUP_MEMBERS_ATTRIBUTE_NAME>

<GROUP_ATTRIBUTE name="cn">cn</GROUP_ATTRIBUTE>
<GROUP_ATTRIBUTE name="member">member</GROUP_ATTRIBUTE>
<ACCESS_GROUP_NAME>icilszx</ACCESS_GROUP_NAME> <!-- Access group name: if specified, users must belong to this group in order to enter SpagoBI -->
  <!-- this attribute has to contain the list of users belonging to this group, in case the ACCESS_GROUP_NAME is specified -->
```

Appreciate someone can give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`<GROUP_SEARCH_PATH>ou=Groups</GROUP_SEARCH_PATH> <!-- SpagoBI will look for groups under this node -->`
*for this row ou=name of ou as I'm not sure as your ou's name is Groups or not*

`<GROUP_OBJECT_CLASS>groupOfNames</GROUP_OBJECT_CLASS> <!-- class for groups' objects -->`
*this line I use groupOfUniqueNames*

```
<GROUP_MEMBERS_ATTRIBUTE_NAME>member</GROUP_MEMBERS_ATTRIBUTE_NAME>
```

*this line you need to input ou name as you  want user on this group can be access or blank for test*